# flex 4.6 set browser url like window.location for pages within same base url

Tags: apache-flex, url, href, navigatetourl

flex 4.6

seems like a noob Q. but I would like to change the browser url page not domain, from `http://myUrl.com/page1` to `http://myUrl.com/page2`. I have tied IBrowserManager .setFragment(page2) this seems to add to the existing url `http://myUrl.com/page1#page2`.

Is there a way to do this?

I am looking to do two things,

1. reset the application to its load state if the user logs out or session ends etc - ie reload the page and start again `http://myUrl.com/page1`
2. as the site will not be updated in one go, if the user reaches the end of the app and needs to navigate to a html page from the app loaded via page1 `http://myUrl.com/page2`.

Thx 
Art

Comment: I think you're on the right path with the browser manager.  Can you show us specifically what you've been doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BrowserManager` is supposed to manage application states and support inner history of Flex application. `setFragment` method controls only url part after `#`, which actually doesn't reload the page. What you need is `navigateToURL` function.

```
navigateToURL("http://myUrl.com/page2", "_self");
```

Comment: thx for the pointer @Timofei I have adjusted the code above and parsers fine but no outbound request seems to be made. Am I missing another basic component?  thx Art